# Thymeleaf and jQuery quotes fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to generate a valid span tag via jQuery:

```
$("#commentsSection").append("<span class='myClass'>");

$("#commentsSection").append("</span>");
```

I'm using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf and such html won't render due to:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
$("#commentsSection").append("<span class="myClass">");
```

Should I esape quotes somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your javascript is directly in the html file then surround it with a CDATA-Block so thymeleaf doesn't try to render it.

```
<script>
  // <![CDATA[
  .
  . your code
  .
  // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes or use `'` single quote inside.

```
$("#commentsSection").append("<span class='myClass'>");
```

or

```
$("#commentsSection").append("<span class=\"myClass\">");
```

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute "class" associated with an  element type  "span".

Answer (score 0):

You need to put escape char like this,

```
"<span class=\"myClass\">"
```

Hope it works!